# Good literature on harmonic maps between manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

I want to show that a closed geodesic in a Riemannian manifold $(N,g)$ is a harmonic map between $(S^1, \mathrm{dt^2})$ and $(N,g)$ and similar things. I have a background in differential geometry, but harmonic maps are new to me.
Do you know good literature on the subject?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add `reference-request` to the tags.

Comment: That geodesic is a harmonic map follows from the definition of harmonic maps. The canonical reference to harmonic maps is of course [this one](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/books/items/00000076/index.php)